# Slim API on XAMPP - Delayed response on localhost

Tags: php, xampp, slim

I'm having an issue with hosting a Slim API on XAMPP in local environment. When I access the API via localhost, I notice that it takes about 15-20 seconds to receive a response from requests. I'm trying to understand what the causes of this delay could be and how I can resolve them.

Here is some additional information about my environment and setup:

I'm using XAMPP version 3.3.0.
I have successfully configured the Slim API following the official documentation.
The problem occurs with both GET requests and POST requests.
The API code doesn't appear to contain any particularly heavy operations or infinite loops that could cause delays indeed it must print only a hard coded json in the index.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could check or what approach I could take to resolve this Slim API response delay issue on XAMPP locally?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: This could be caused by various factors, including misconfigurations in XAMPP, issues with network settings etc. I would try to check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem of the delay in Slim API responses on my local XAMPP environment. After careful investigation, I found that the root cause of the problem was not related to XAMPP at all, but was a MySQL database connection issue within the API.

In fact, it appears that database connections were not handled correctly in the API code, which caused the delay in request responses. After adding logs and using debugging tools, I discovered that the problem was that the API was unable to connect to the MySQL database, which was unreachable.

To solve this mystery, I had to optimize database queries and strengthen error handling mechanisms in the API. Once I addressed the database connection issue and made the API more robust in handling such situations, I finally saw a noticeable improvement in the API's performance.

In short, the delay in Slim API responses on XAMPP was not caused by XAMPP itself at all, but by a MySQL database connection issue, which I successfully resolved by identifying and fixing the database unreachability issue.

Comment: Congratulations.